# Length of values 'x' does not match the size inferred by the shape 'no of rows' in Tensorflow JS for classification problem

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I am trying i basic Tensorflow JS model for text classification But I am getting this shape error

```
(node:11400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Length of values '33693' does not match the size inferred by the shape '10000'.
```

Here is my code

```
var X_Train = // tokenize sentences
var Y_Train = // encoded label
const xs = tf.tensor2d(X_Train);
const ys = Y_Train;
console.log('Shape of X '); 
console.log(X_Train[0]);
console.log(xs);
console.log('Shape of Y '); 
console.log(Y_Train[0]);
console.log(ys);

const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.embedding({
inputDim: 4,
outputDim: 10,
inputLength: 10,
trainable: true
}));
model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid'}));
 model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError',optimizer: 'adam'});
model.fit(xs,tf.stack(ys))
```

Here is my Output

> Shape of X
> [
> 1996, 7357,  1997,
> 1037, 2931,  6398,
> 1999, 1996, 13678,
> 1012
> ]
> Tensor {
> kept: false,
> isDisposedInternal: false,
> shape: [ 1000, 10 ],
> dtype: 'float32',
> size: 10000,
> strides: [ 10 ],
> dataId: { id: 2 },
> id: 2,
> rankType: '2'
> }
> Shape of Y
> 0
> [
> 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,
> 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
> 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
> 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
> 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59,
> 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71,
> 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83,
> 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90,  3, 91, 92, 93, 94,
> 95, 96, 97, 98,
> ... 900 more items
> ]
> (node:18640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Length of values '33693' does not match the size inferred by the shape '10000'.
> at assert (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:337:15)
> at new TensorBuffer (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:3591:13)
> at Object.buffer (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:7400:12)
> at MathBackendCPU.bufferSync (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-backend-cpu\dist\tf-backend-cpu.node.js:239:25)
> at Object.gatherV2 [as kernelFunc] (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-backend-cpu\dist\tf-backend-cpu.node.js:6592:24)
> at kernelFunc (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4666:32)
> at C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4727:27
> at Engine.scopedRun (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4539:23)
> at Engine.runKernelFunc (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4723:14)
> at Engine.runKernel (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4595:21)
> at gather_ (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:14426:19)
> at Object.gather__op [as gather] (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:5519:29)
> at C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-layers\dist\tf-layers.node.js:18091:20
> at C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4529:22
> at Engine.scopedRun (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4539:23)
> at Engine.tidy (C:\Users\project\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4528:21)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:18640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1)
> (node:18640) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
> not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
> code.

I tried to use different model architecture but still ended up with same error. when I change the loss function I still got some different error. Any idea what am I missing or what model architecture I need to use for that kind of data

Comment: The shape of `xs` and `tf.stack(ys)` does not match what the model is expecting

Answer (score 0):

The shape of `xs` and `tf.stack(ys)` does not match what the model is expecting. Here is an example to help you see the shape expected

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.embedding({
inputDim: 4,
outputDim: 10,
inputLength: 10,
trainable: true
}));
model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid'}));

model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError',optimizer: 'adam'});
await model.fit(tf.ones([1, 10]),tf.tensor([1], [1, 1]))
```